# Why won't the "Migrate from" option appear on my Heart Gold game?

Tags: nintendo-ds, pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

Here are the steps I've made:

1. Pokemon Heart Gold is completed, all 16 badges, have the National dex, reached Pal Park in Fuschia city, and had the guy explaining to me how to use it.
2. Pokemon Emerald is also completed, the Elite 4 is beaten, National dex is obtained, and battle frontier is unlocked.
3. I insert both into my DS Lite, the opening screen shows both.
4. I enter HG and in the start menu, the Migrate From option won't appear. I've scrolled down.

Heart Gold is EU and Emerald is US, I've read that it shouldn't matter as long as they are both the same language (for example, [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/946308-pokemon-platinum-version/49552348) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/925601-pokemon-diamond-version/44191394)).

I can play Emerald just fine on the DS, as well as HG. Other games of the 3rd generation give the same symptoms (although, I haven't completed those).

What might cause this phenomenon? What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Did you get all of the games from the same place? They may be fakes, which do not work in the Pal Park. Try looking at [this guide](https://reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1i36bn/spotting_the_new_breed_of_fake_generation_iii/) to detect if it is a fake. Here's a summary:

1. Check the Nintendo logo, Nintendo Seal of Quality, ESRB rating, and GBA logo.
2. Make sure the game doesn't give a warning when trying to load the page.
3. Make sure the label is metallic, not just glossy.
4. Make sure the plastic is colored after the name of the game, and in the case of Pokemon Ruby, Pokemon Sapphire, and Pokemon Emerald is transparent.

Comment: I've already performed that check (based on that very guide), for my GBA games, and the DS games are from official retailers, so I didn't check, but I will when I get home.

Comment: Trusting retailers is a bad idea. They only sell the product, and very rarely have good knowledge of it. For example the UK somehow sells 1800 tonnes of Manuka honey annually, despite the production rate capping out around 1700 tonnes.